# How can I automatically create and broadcast transactions using NodeJS?

Tags: transactions, wallet, api, nodejs

I have a:

- Wallet public/private key pair with X BTC
- Wallet address I want to sent Y BTC to

I'm developing an app in NodeJS and trying to initiate payments automatically. I'm very confused how I'm supposed to do this.

From my research, it seems like I have to generate some "raw" transaction hash, then encrypt that again with my private key, then I'm supposed to broadcast that encrypted data.

Is there some library/some simple API that can help me do this? I don't want to have to run a bitcoin server if I don't have to...

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example: https://github.com/OutCast3k/coinbin/
This app does everything you need